# xfce4-power-manager not updating; ACPI finding an unknown battery but working fine?

Tags: debian, xfce, power-management, acpi, battery

I recently upgraded my Asus S56CA Ultrabook and unfortunately my battery indicator in xfce4 stopped working. I am running Debian 8 (Jessie). `uname -a` gives me this:

```
Linux 3.14-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.13-2 (2014-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The battery indicator in the system tray is not updating at all to anything. If I start the computer with the AC plugged in, it will continue to say it is plugged in at the same percentage it was at when I started my computer even though I unplugged the cord.

Running `xfce4-power-manager --debug` returns this message:

```
Xfce Power Manager: Another power manager is already running
```

Despite the message, I am almost positive I have no other power manager running on my computer (although I do not know how to check to make sure this is the case).

I have tried to purge and reinstall acpi* and xfce4-power-manager* with no success.

Running `acpi -V` gives me this when the AC cord is plugged in:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 97%
Battery 0: design capacity 2950 mAh, last full capacity 2424 mAh = 82%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 51.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 108.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 110.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: TEFN no state information available
Cooling 2: T_VR no state information available
Cooling 3: TAMB no state information available
Cooling 4: TSKN no state information available
Cooling 5: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 9: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 10: LCD 0 of 100
```

and when the cord is unplugged, `acpi -V` gives me this:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 97%, 02:59:50 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 2950 mAh, last full capacity 2424 mAh = 82%
Adapter 0: off-line
Thermal 0: ok, 49.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 108.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 110.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: TEFN no state information available
Cooling 2: T_VR no state information available
Cooling 3: TAMB no state information available
Cooling 4: TSKN no state information available
Cooling 5: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 9: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 10: LCD 0 of 100
```

I am not sure if this is an error as well, but is the battery supposed to be displayed as unknown?

I would like to have my **battery indicator fixed** first and foremost, then any other issues would be bonus. Any alternatives for a battery indicator would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this command produce as output when plugged in and not plugged in? `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

Comment: Hi @Ramesh, thanks for the reply. I have copied the output of ``upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`` in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/MXSJEkEN Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Ramesh, but I was wondering if you had a chance to look at the output I have posted? Don't mean to rush you or anything! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry. I looked at it. But I did not have much of information.

Comment: No worries @Ramesh, I seem to have found what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue within Jessie itself.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755234

**UPDATE: 9/23/2014**

A fix for this bug is in the new xfce4-power-manager-plugins 1.4.0 in sid.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755234#188